# Trouble setting color of Snackbar MaterialUI

Tags: material-ui, tailwind-css

Trying to set the background color of a MaterialUI Snackbar. From other answers online, it seems like I should try to target the SnackbarContent element. My code to center that element works, but somehow the background color is not changing. I am using Tailwind. Any advice is appreciated

```
 <Snackbar
          open={true}
          anchorOrigin={{ vertical: "bottom", horizontal: "center" }}
          ContentProps={{}}
          TransitionComponent={Slide}
          autoHideDuration={3000}
          onClose={() => {
            setSnackbarOpen(false);
          }}
        >
          <SnackbarContent
            className="flex justify-center bg-slate-200"
            message={<p>Changes submitted!</p>}
          />
</Snackbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the SnackbarContent you can use sx to set up the background color which you want, here is the code example you can try.

```js
<SnackbarContent
            sx={{backgroundColor: '#0099ff'}}
            message={<p>Note archived</p>}
          />
```

It will look like this:
[image]

Hope this can help you.